# Breadcrumbs in highchart-treemap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, treemap, breadcrumbs

I wanted to know if its possible to design breadcrubms in highchart treemap. For now, there is only a back button which helps in getting back to the first level from 2nd drill down. I am expecting something like this
for example : if first level has tiles like animals, vegetables, fruits.
second level would be animal names, vegetable names etc.
so when i click on animal tile, it will display all the animal names and the breadcrumb should look like : 
project>>animals
and if i select  vegetables, it should display something like this
project>>vegetables
 and i should be able to navigate to the previous level using these breadcrumbs, instead of the traditional back button which is got on the right side of the treemap. I wanted to know if that kind of feature is supported by highcharts!

Comment: Unfortunately, by default it is not supported in Highcharts, it may be possible to add similar functionality manually. Additionaly it may be possible to change text of your button to your breadcrumbs using lang.drillUpText: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.drillUpText

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, can you please let me know how to proceed with the breadcrumbs manually? Is it feasible to link the chart and the breadcrubs as there is no inbuilt feature. Can you please provide me with a fiddle link?

Comment: Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/73h75jqv/

Comment: Can you show an example of that with the treemap? Don't think treemap has the same drill up/down events