# Breadcrumbs in Highcharts large treemap

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I have a requirement to show breadcrumbs in High charts large tree map as we drill down the level.

As we drill down, need to show the name in the breadcrumbs and user should be able to navigate.

Something similar to the [Breadcrumbs in highchart-treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645016/breadcrumbs-in-highchart-treemap)
But I could not find any solution. Let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Drilldown events are not available for a treemap series. Instead you can use point click event for displaying/destroying breadcrumb element - [a label](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label).

Disable drill up button:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype.showDrillUpButton = function () {
  this.drillUpButton = {
    destroy: function () {}
  }
}
```

Function for creating a breadcrumb element can look like this:

```
function makeNode(id, name, series, prev) {
  const chart = series.chart
  const node = {
    id,
    name
  }
  let x = chart.plotLeft

  if (prev) {
    const { width, height, y } = prev.element.getBBox()
    x = width + prev.x + 10
    node.prev = prev
    prev.next = node

        prev.element.attr({
      anchorX: x,
      anchorY: chart.plotTop - 20 + height / 2
    })
  }

  node.destroyNext = function () {
    const next = this.next
    if (next) {
      next.destroyNext()
      next.element.destroy()
      delete this.next
      delete chart.bread[next.id]
    }
  }

  const element = node.element = chart.renderer.label(name, x, chart.plotTop - 20, 'callout').attr({
    fill: '#FFFFEF',
    stroke: 'gray',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    padding: 5,
    r: 5,
    zIndex: 10
  }).add()

  element.on('click', () => {
    node.destroyNext()
    node.element.attr({
      anchorX: undefined,
      anchorY: undefined
    })
    if (chart.series[0].rootNode !== '') series.drillToNode(id)
  })

  node.x = x
  return node
}
```

Call that function on chart load:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.bread = {
        '': makeNode('', this.series[0].name, this.series[0])
      }
    }
  }
},
```

and on point click event:

```
  plotOptions: {
   series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(e) {
            const hasChildren = !!this.node.childrenTotal

            if (hasChildren) {
              const bread = this.series.chart.bread
              bread[this.id] = makeNode(this.id, this.name, this.series, bread[this.node.parent])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

## Example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/z0zc1btk/
[image: treemap breadcrumb]

Comment: Wow. Thank yous so much :). It worked perfectly for my requirement